# Cannot find module vertx/container

Tags: javascript, vert.x

I installed the latest version of *Vert.x*, **3.0.0**, and pointed the path in system variables to /bin directory. I have the latest version of java installed on my machine. I am getting the following error when trying to run the below code:

```
C:\Users\test\>vertx run app.js Failed in deploying verticle
javax.script.ScriptException: Error: Cannot find module vertx/container in <eval > at line number 141 at column number 6
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException( NashornScriptEngine.java:467)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptE ngine.java:451)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptE ngine.java:403)
```

My verticle:

```js
var container = require("vertx/container");
container.deployModule("io.vertx~mod-web-server~3.0.0-final", {
  port: 8080,
  host: "localhost"
});
```

Comment: Could you please provide the whole error message?

Comment: here is the complete error.. 
C:\Users\test\>vertx run app.js

Failed in deploying verticle
javax.script.ScriptException: Error: Cannot find module vertx/container in <eval
> at line number 141 at column number 6
        at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(
NashornScriptEngine.java:467)
        at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptE
ngine.java:451)
        at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptE
ngine.java:403)
        at

Comment: Line *141* doesn't match your provided verticle code. You would rather provide what you have really done so you can get the requested help.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this... This is a very basic example and I am just trying to run this verticle. I get a long error. But, the first error I see is 'Cannot find module vertx/container'. All  paths are pointing to correct folders. I set the system path to vertx/bin folder and it is recognizing vertx commands and java home is correct. Please advise...

Comment: Sorry @Venkat for insisting, but even the simplest examples can hold some clues... Otherwise you would have seen the example working without any issue. Please update the main post with your whole vertice source code.

Comment: I have the same problem. Debian 7.9, Oracle Java 8, vertx 3.1.0. Just tried to run the example code from http://vertx.io/vertx2/install.html: javax.script.ScriptException: Error: Cannot find module vertx in <eval> at line number 141 at column number 6 at...NashornScriptEngine.java:467 There is definitely no line 141 in 4 lines of script.

Answer (score 2):

For those who also facing this issue on this: The equivalent JavaScript for Vert.x 3 is here on [github](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/core-examples/src/main/js/io/vertx/example/core/http/simple/server.js)

**No need to require('vertx') anymore, and response is a method now.**